# How to map inside another map in react without duplicate of the render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am having the list of all the objects in the array

```
let array = [
  { name: "Galaxy S22", storage: "128GB" },
  { name: "Galaxy S22 5G", storage: "128GB" },
  { name: "Galaxy S22 Ultra", storage: "256GB" },
  { name: "Galaxy S22", storage: "256GB" }
 ];
```

I have an another object which holds the object with name and its storages

```
  const storages = {
    Galaxy S22: ["128GB", "256GB"],
    Galaxy S22 5G: ["128GB"],
    Galaxy S22 Ultra: ["256GB"]
   }
```

I am trying to display in the UI respective storages for the respective brand name. But i am able to see all the storages for all the brands

[image: All the storages in all the brands]

```
function generateAndDisplayRadioButtons(list, storages) {
   return (
    <div>
        {
            list.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <div key={item.name}>
                        {storages[item.name]?.map((storage)=>{
                           return (
                                <div key={storage} className='flexCss'>
                                <input className="radioCss" type="radio" name={item.name} value={storage} />
                                <strong>{storage}</strong>
                            </div>
                            )
                        })

                        }
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }

    </div>
)
};
```

In the render i am trying to display with

```
<div>{generateAndDisplayRadioButtons(array, storages)}</div>
```

Comment: You must be mapping/looping over `array` somewhere else in your code to generate those cards. It's in that map where you want to grab the current `name` of the item to determine the associated storage values, not in a new separate map over `list`/`array`

Comment: Also this looks like [tag:reactjs], not sure why [tag:angularjs] is included in your tags.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the keys of storages object within double quotes.

```
  const storages = {
    "Galaxy S22": ["128GB", "256GB"],
    "Galaxy S22 5G": ["128GB"],
    "Galaxy S22 Ultra": ["256GB"],
  };
```

With that included I have run the code in my machine. It works fine with the following output on the browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gT3x.png)

You have Glaxy S22 two times in the list array which is printing the same content twice.

Answer (score -2):

You have a mismatch in the structure.
I think you should change your function to this:

```
function generateAndDisplayRadioButtons(list, storages) {
return (
    <div>
        {list.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.name}>
                {storages[item.name]?.map((storage) => (
                    <div key={storage} className='flexCss'>
                        <input className="radioCss" type="radio" name={item.name} value={storage} />
                        <strong>{storage}</strong>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

}